# How to specify case insensitive mode in ansible lineinfile regexp?

Tags: regex, ansible

Simple question.
I'm trying to match "UseDns", "usedns" and other variations.

```
- name: Disable DNS checking on login (huge speedup)
  sudo: true
  lineinfile:
    dest:   "/etc/ssh/sshd_config"
    regexp:   "^[# \t]*[Uu][Ss][Ee][Dd][Nn][Ss] "
    # how does one specify case insensitive regexp in lineinfile?
    line:   "UseDNS no"
    state:  "present"
    create:  true
    insertafter: EOF
  notify:
    - sshd restart
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ansible uses Python [re module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html). You can use [inline modifiers](http://regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html), such as `(?ism)` in your pattern. Use the **i** for case-insensitive matching:

```
regexp:   "(?i)^[# \t]*usedns "
```

Inline modifiers apply to the part of the regular experssion *to the right* of the modifier, and can be disabled with a `-` e.g. `(?-i)`. This can be applied to implement case-insensitivity to only a part of a regular expression.

For example, the regex `(?i)use(?-i)DNS` should match `useDNS` and `UseDNS`, but not `useDns` or `USEdns`.

Comment: That's a really useful answer - except that using [pythex]( https://pythex.org/), `(?i)pattern` works, but I get a syntax error if I try to re-enable sensitivity with (?-i)